# Unable to retrieve data from http site to https using XMLHttpRequest()

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xmlhttprequest

I have a site hosted on `https://` in which I want to pull data from the site which shows the properties of the shares. The URL which returns the data is:

http://ir1.euroinvestor.com/asp/ir/xmlirmultiiso2.aspx?companyid=281191

The code which I have developed to get the data is as follows:

```
function GetSharesUpdate(){
    // makeing AJAX calls to the web service for getting the share update    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Set up xhr request
    xhr.open("GET", "http://ir1.euroinvestor.com/asp/ir/xmlirmultiiso2.aspx?companyid=281191", true);   // Open the request
    xhr.responseType = "";   // Set the type of response expected    
    xhr.send();
    //  Asynchronously wait for the data to return
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == xhr.DONE) {
            var tempoutput = xhr.responseXML;
            alert(tempoutput);
        }
    }
    //  Report errors if they happen
    xhr.addEventListener("error", function (e) {
        console.error("Error: " + e + " Could not load url.");
    }, false);       
}
```

I am getting the error on the statement `xhr.send();` which is as below:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://[SiteUrl]' was loaded over HTTPS,
>   but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://ir1.euroinvestor.com/asp/ir/xmlirmultiiso2.aspx?companyid=281191'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

If I change the URL to  `https` i.e.

https://ir1.euroinvestor.com/asp/ir/xmlirmultiiso2.aspx?companyid=281191

then `xhr.send();` is executed without any error but I am getting `xhr.responseXML` null.

What should I make changes in my code to make it working?

Comment: There are four slashes (`/`) in your second url. Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for drawing attention. It was a typing mistake while adding the post.

Comment: It is executed without any error? It isn't when I run it: *VM155 nizaqapusu.js:6 GET https://ir1.euroinvestor.com/asp/ir/xmlirmultiiso2.aspx?companyid=281191 net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE* and when I visit the URL Chrome complains that the SSL cert is for a different hostname.

Comment: If you open the site with **http**, you'll see it returns XML, but if you open it with **https**, it returns Privacy Error - the site doesn't support SSL, so you cannot do that with simple AJAX - you are going to need a proxy.

Comment: So is there a way to call with `http://`?

Comment: Setup a proxy on your server and call your server instead. Your server will be on **https**, so browser won't block the request. Then your server will make a request to the **http** resource and will return it to you without modifying.

Comment: The server is not accessible to me as the site is hosted by Microsoft. It's a SharePointo online site, but the page works like aspx page to develop the JS code.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is you are doing ajax request to non-https domain but your domain has SSL installed.

The second problem is Cross origin request `CORS`, you will have this problem even you solve first (ie. even you try ajax request from non-http domain).

Since you are requesting data from another website this is most likely to happen unless the requested server is configured to serve requests for you domain 
To solve this you need to call the data from your server(proxy server)  or have the requested server configured to allow requests from your domain.

See more - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS